# Powershell SQL module errors out when trying to use sqlserver cmdlets

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016, invoke-sqlcmd

I have the sqlserver module imported into Powershell
[Get-Module result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gERjt.png)

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                
ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                               
Manifest   21.0.17099 sqlserver                           
{Add-RoleMember, Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Add- 
SqlAvailabilityGroupListenerStaticIp...
Script     0.0        SqlServer
```

However I still recieve the following error when trying to use Invoke-sqlcmd:

[Invoke-sqlcmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIM5L.png)

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd 
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
The specified module could not 
be found.
```

I have tried re-importing the module and it imports successfully but it still errors out when attempting to use this. Intellisense is even detecting the module's cmdlets

Comment: I believe there is a conflict between SQLPS and Sqlserver modules somehow. I tested this on anothermachine, and the SQLServer module is not present, only the sqlps.

Comment: There should be a file named `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll` in the same directory as the sqlserver module: `(Get-Module sqlserver).path`. If some of those files are missing, you may need to reinstall the module